# Auth0 NuGet packages for Xamarin Forms 5.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, auth0

I'm building a new Xamarin mobile app using Xamarin Forms 5.0 and tried to install `Auth0.OidcClient.iOS` and `Auth0.OidcClient.Android` as suggested by the instructions on Auth0 website here: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/xamarin

I get an error that tells me that these packages are NOT compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 -- see below:
[image]

What packages am I supposed to use with a new Xamarin Forms app?

P.S. I'm on Visual Studio 2022 17.1.0 and the app is a Xamarin Forms app with the following version numbers in the project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2196" />  
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the name suggests `Auth0.OidcClient.iOS` should be installed in your **iOS** project and `Auth0.OidcClient.Android` should be installed in your **Android** project.  You are apparently trying to install them in the shared Forms project

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you for your help!